# sed command in the JenkinsFile and Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the JenkinsFile below which contains two sed commands. But I faced different issues with string interpolation when I cat the file.

Do you know how I can run it inside the JenkinsFile?
Thanks in advance.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {nodejs "NodeJS 6.7.0"}
    stages {
        stage('checking out gitlab branch master') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/development']]])
            }
        }
        stage('executing release process') {
            environment {
                ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY = credentials('sandbox-gms-password')
            }
            steps {
                sh 'cp bowerrc.template .bowerrc'
                sh 'sed -i -e "s/username/zest-jenkins/g" .bowerrc'
                sh 'sed -i -e "s/password/${ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY}/g" .bowerrc'
                sh 'cat .bowerrc'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the commands in single "**sh**" block, please take the reference from the below:-

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {nodejs "NodeJS 6.7.0"}
stages {
    stage('checking out gitlab branch master') {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/development']]])
        }
    }
    stage('executing release process') {
        environment {
            ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY = credentials('sandbox-gms-password')
        }
        steps {
            sh '''
                  cp bowerrc.template .bowerrc
                  sed -i -e "s/username/zest-jenkins/g" .bowerrc
                  sed -i -e "s/password/${ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY}/g" .bowerrc
                  cat .bowerrc
               '''
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: My mistake, the problem was different. 
It works in both cases now! :)